# React how to pass data to parent navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-router, heading

I have a navigation toolbar, with H1 in it.
I also various sub content for each page, as child component.
How can I pass the title information, from the child page component, to the parent navigation?

I've tried to use Context, but it only propagate from Parent to Childs.

Her is a simplified exemple:

```
const App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <toolbar>
          <h1>{myTitleAccordingToPage}</h1>
        </toolbar>
        <main>
          {this.props.children}
        </main>
      </div>
    )
  }
})

const A = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Content for A page
      </div>
    )
  }
})

const B = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Content for B page
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

Comment: You may want to set (state of) the title information in the parent navigation and pass it down to the children via props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract state for your navigation either into a store, or somewhere else, and propagate that state to your application via props.

```
var page = {
  title: 'foo'
  otherData: ''
}

ReactDOM.render( <App page={ page }, element )
```

Now your top-level component knows about the state and can filter accordingly down to its children, for example, you might change your `App` render function to pass different bits of the application state down to different children i.e.

*(I'm passing props explicitly here to show what is going on, and using a pure function to render, use a class and render method if that is more comfortable for you, the advantage of only ever passing props is that it is easier to make your functions pure, which has many advantages)*

```
const App = props => {
  <div>
    <Toolbar title={ props.page.title } />
    <Main otherData={ props.page.otherData />
  </div>
}
```

Now you have created top-down data flow, making your application more predictable and possibly paving the way to use the pure render function to maybe give you performance boosts for free. The key with top-down data-flow is really making your application more predictable, which should translate into testability, and thus reliability, and makes hacking on your application easier.

The [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) module can help with creating structures like this. There is a small learning phase when adopting the module but the benefits for an app like the one you are creating should outweigh this and the speed of development once learnt may very well outweigh any learning outlay you invest into it.

Comment: Thanks, this sound like a better solution that two way binding. So the solution is not much about to structure of the app, but more about to store the page information in the store, and use the proper data flow.

Comment: Many of the other good stuff surrounding React works better if you employ a top down data flow. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Possible it's time to use Flex https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/dispatcher.html#content

Usable approuch to two way data binding http://voidcanvas.com/react-tutorial-two-way-data-binding/

Original documentation to two way data binding, but mixin now is now supported https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html
( For mixin possible to use react-mixin npm package )

EDIT:
There is an opinion at comments that: "two-way data-binding is often a bad idea, and if your application makes more sense with two-way data binding then React should probably not be the framework to employ". So you need to rearrange your application architecture to avoid using two-way data binding if possible. Use flux instead.

Comment: React is designed from a top-down data-flow stand point, whilst two-way data binding can be hacked in, it breaks many (most) of the advantages of using React in the first place. The correct way is to extract state and pass properties from the top level components down to the lower level and avoid the mess that is two-way data binding altogether.

Comment: The question is: "How can I pass the title information, from the child page component, to the parent navigation?" We can pass properties from parent to child. But how we can pass events or states from child to parent without two-way data binding or flux dispatcher? How two way data binding was not so good - it is necessary to use some times.

Comment: When state can be updated as part of navigation with react-router - yes of courese, we do not use two way binding. But if event is independent from navigation, for example "change currency" select under left menu, need to send event to top bar to show cash. React router is not helpful, and pooling from top to children is not solution of course.

Comment: There is much information about why two-way data-binding is often a very bad idea so no need to list links here, a tenet of React addresses these concerns. In the posters example it is trivial to restructure the application to use top-down data flow, there is simply no use-case here (other than developer comfort) that requires two-way data binding. Please see my answer if you are unsure why this is trivial. Infact, I'd go so far as to say that if your application makes more sense with two-way data binding then React should probably not be the framework to employ.

Comment: "How can I pass the title information, from the child page component, to the parent navigation?" -> the answer to this question is to employ other methods so you do not need to ask this question. The example presented here makes this a trivial concern.